Running spring boot application with docker-compose.yml fails (with localstack image)
I am running the application with the following docker-compose.yml to verify localstack image is running. But fails with an error message,
"Suppressed: org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.ServiceNotReadyException: Immediate disconnect while connecting to port 4510".

o.s.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m  Container localstack-main  Healthy
o.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

Did I miss anything?
services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME:-localstack-main}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"            # LocalStack Gateway
      - "127.0.0.1:4510-4559:4510-4559"  # external services port range
    environment:
      # LocalStack configuration: https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/configuration/
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG:-0}
    volumes:
      - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"

Running as spring boot application.

Have you checked if those ports are free? Or if you have the necessary rights to bind to those ports?
You can check running a generic nginx container on those ports and see what that does.
"docker run --rm -p "127.0.0.1:4510:80" nginx"
